Meaning of 皮がたわむ here
I encountered this sentence from some NSFW material. The context is that a couple was about to begin a sexual intercourse. A girl was putting a condom on her boyfriend's straight erect penis. She commented

実際はこれくらい皮{かわ}がたわむ感じなんですね

I am uncertain what 皮がたわむ means here. I think 皮 likely refers to condom's rubber skin and たわむ refers the stretching of that skin?

If you look up たわむ in the dictionary, it's usually defined as "to bend due to external force". However, in practice, たわむ is often used interchangeably with たるむ, i.e., in situations where something bends due to a lack of sufficient external force.

Some may describe this as a たわんだロープ (because it's pulled downwards by an external force called gravity), but some may describe it as a たるんだロープ (because there's not enough tension to keep it straight). In reality, these are often used without strict distinctions.
In your case as well, I think 皮がたわんでいる means there is an unstretched, non-flat part in the "skin". Some may argue such a use of たわむ is technically incorrect, though.

I see. So, you are saying that she is talking about his genital in a flaccid state?

@weeab00 Didn't you say this 皮 likely refers to the condom itself? If that's the case, the sentence would mean the condom was a little longer or looser than she had expected.
